# Google Tag Manager- Tracking Dynamic changing Text in ad

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, universal-analytics

In my client website on the homepage I have ad and have 3 text link in it when user click on the text they are directed to the page. I want to track how many people have clicked the particular text.

Currently I am able to track the data using "Click Text" functionality in GTM. But the my concern is that client changes the ad text without informing us. Due to which TAG & Triggers doesn't get fired and data is not getting tracked. Can anybody help me on how to define the TAG and Trigger which will fire even if the text of the ad changes dynamically (without informing us)

[image]

I have highlighted ad text code area
 below are the 3 text link that are placed currently

**Test Story 4**

**Gemino Sit Tum Typicus**

**Lenis Persto Voco**

Also I am not good with javascript. If some one help me with script.

Thanks advance

Comment: Can you show some things you've attempted, some code, or how you've configured your tags?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using Google Analytics.

If Click Text works fine for you, than you can use it as a value of Action field in GA event tag.

Also you can add class attribute to a tags and use Click Classes equals value of this attribute in firing trigger.

Comment: Thanks Mrburu I am Universal Analytics. My concern is that for all the three text are using same class name. Also with click text the problem is that client changes the text with informing us due to which click text doesn't work as the text changes. I am looking for solution in which even if text changes (without informing us) the TAG should fire. PLease help me with solution

Comment: As I sad, you should use Click Text in Action field of GA event tag but not in trigger. This way you will track text changes and clicks on elements with different text and same class. In your page code you are using classes for div tags and not for < a > tags. Try to add classes to < a > tags and use it in your click trigger (tag will fire only if user clicks on < a > tag with some class)

Comment: got it Sir Thank you. My bad was not able get  u r suggestion at first go.